# optimization volume of the largest rectangular box

Tags: calculus, optimization

Find the volume of the largest rectangular box in the first octant with three faces in the coordinate planes, and one vertex in the plane x +3 y + 6 z = 18

Comment: Which method are you expected to use?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe Lagrange Multipliers

Comment: Please edit your question to include your working so far with Lagrange multipliers, then probably someone will be able to suggest what you should do next.

Comment: maximize V = xyz with g=x +3 y + 6 z = 18 and x,y,z > 0

Comment: Using Lagrange Multipliers, 
∇V = λ∇g ==> <yz, xz, xy>

Comment: Your "Lagrange equation" should read $ \ \langle \ yz, xz, xy \ \rangle \ = \ \lambda \cdot \langle \ 1, 3, 6 \ \rangle \ . $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a point $A = (x,y,z)$ on the plane so that $x + 3y + 6z = 18$.

The volume $V$ of the box is $V = xyz$. So we find $max(V)$ with conditions $x + 3y + 6z = 18$ and $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^{\text{nonneg}}$.

Use $g(x,y,z) = x + 3y + 6z = 18$. So

$$V'(x) = yz = rg'(x) = r$$

$$V'(y) = xz = rg'(y) = 3r$$

$$V'(z) = xy = rg'(z) = 6r$$

This means $xz = 3yz , xy = 6yz \Rightarrow z(x - 3y) = 0, y(x - 6z) = 0$.

If $z = 0$ or $y = 0$, then $V = 0$ and is not a max. So $$x - 3y = 0 = x - 6z \Rightarrow y = \frac{x}{3}, z = \frac{x}{6}$$

$$\Rightarrow x + 3\left(\frac{x}{3}\right) + 6\left(\frac{x}{6}\right) = 18$$

$$\Rightarrow 3x = 18 \Rightarrow x = 6, y = 2, z = 1$$ So $max(V) = 6*2*1 = 12$.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a non-calculus solution.

We want to maximize $xyz$ subject to the condition $x+3y+6z=18$.

Let $a=x$, $b=3y$, and $c=6z$. We want to maximize $\frac{abc}{18}$, or equivalently $abc$, subject to $a+b+c=18$.

By the Arithmetic Mean Geometric Mean Inequality, known to "contest kids" as AM/GM, we have for non-negative $a,b,c$ that
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\ge (abc)^{1/3},$$
with equality precisely when $a=b=c$.

Thus $abc$ is maximized when $x=3y=6z$. The maximum value has $abc=(18/3)^3$, and hence $xyz=12$.